# How do I link to a different part of the page in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I'm writing up a page in Markdown. And I'm trying to implement something like the following:

`<a href="#about">Something</a>`

What is the recommended way of going about doing this? I am using Jekyll Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `about` anchor is defined like this:

```
<a id="about"></a>About
```

This can be added together with other elements, for example:

```
## <a id="about"></a>About
```

Then you should be able to use the usual markdown link:

```
[Something](#about)
```